# Why do I see massive time difference when closing an excel spreadsheet on different computers?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have developed on my Mac, a small (5 worksheets and ~230Ko) workbook that contains many VBA macros.

When I use this same workbook on other mac computers (I have tested like 4 with different OS and faster hardware specs) saving/closing the workbook takes like >30 seconds when it is lightening fast on my old mac that I used to create the xls.

This saving time is a no-go for me.
We tried to check the excel options... they appeared to be the same.

What can I do to diagnose what the difference is, and to fix this issue ?

Comment: Is any code running while(on) closing the workbook? `Workbook_BeforeClose`, `Workbook_BeforeSave`? If so, please show that code. Are there external links or ressources updated while(on) closing the workbook? If so are those ressources reachable with same performance on all computers? But it could also have something to do with other OS dependent differences. Different anti virus macro heuristics for example.

Comment: May be it is the references to libraries that might be missing

Comment: were you saving to your local drive on the developing mac computer, but were saving to a network drive (or a your developing mac's shared drive) on the other computers?

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine solved it.
For future reference:

1. Quit excel
2. in Library/Settings (translated from french YMMV), find and delete com.microsoft.excel.plist
3. Restart